# custom authorizers in Amazon API Gateway 500 error

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I use [Serverless-Authentication-boilerplate](https://github.com/laardee/serverless-authentication-boilerplate) and want to map custom error response. But it always return 500 error.

authorize.js

```
// Authorize
function authorize(event, callback) {
  let providerConfig = config(event);
  try {
    let data = utils.readToken(event.authorizationToken, providerConfig.token_secret);
    console.log("Decrypted data: " + JSON.stringify(data));

    let methodArn = event.methodArn.replace(/(GET|POST|PUT|DELETE)/g, '*').replace(/mgnt.+/g, 'mgnt/*');

    console.log(`Change methodArn to: ${methodArn}`);

    // TODO: handle expiration time validation
    callback(null, utils.generatePolicy(
      data.id, // which is $context.authorizer.principalId
      'Allow',
      methodArn));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    callback('401 Unauthenticated');
  }
}
```

s-function.json

```
responses:{ 
  "401 Unauthenticated.*": {
      "statusCode": "401"
  },
  "default": {
      "statusCode": "200",
      "responseModels": {
        "application/json;charset=UTF-8": "Empty"
      },
      "responseTemplates": {
        "application/json;charset=UTF-8": ""
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After ask to Amazon Web Services.

> Unfortunately the mapping of the Authorizer is not currently configurable and every returned error from a lambda function will map to a 500 status code in API gateway. Moreover, the mapping is performed on an exact string match of the output, so, in order to return the intended 401 Error to the client, you should execute a call to 'context.fail('Unauthorized');.

Finally, I change

```
callback('401 Unauthenticated');
```

to

```
context.fail('Unauthorized');
```

and work fine.

Sharing to whom may encounter this.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere in AWS?

Comment: Here [REF](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html)

Comment: I couldn't find the `fail()` method in the documentation you linked to, however I did [find it here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-using-old-runtime.html#nodejs-prog-model-oldruntime-context-methods).

The documentation states `We recommend you use the callback`, so it appears it is outdated, however I don't see a better solution to return a `401` at the moment.

Comment: The problem is that `context.fail('Unauthorized');` leads to a failed execution of the lambda. And when you have an Alarm that gets triggered on every failed execution of a lambda, you will receive notifications for each Unauthorized request.
This could be an expired token, which is fine and should not lead to an failed lambda execution.

Comment: Adding this does work but I then get the warning Warning: Auth function 'authorizer' returned a promise and also uses a callback!
Is there any Promise safe way of doing this?

Comment: Please don't post links to AWS documentation. It's always useless.

Comment: Web archive version from Jim's REF: https://web.archive.org/web/20160215214818/http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html